# How to disable gradle 'offline mode' in android studio 4.2?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Since I updated my Android Studio to 4.2, I am not able to toggle the Gradle Offline mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

New location to toggle Gradle's offline mode
To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel..

Comment: I am having issues with the toggle offline and online, either way the Android Studio complains saying it's in offline mode. Did you face it too ?

Comment: @nibz please provide more additional supporting information.

Comment: which of the toggles is offline? Highlighted or not?

Comment: @BrianReinhold Highlighted toggle is offline.

Answer (score 37):

from right top you can find toggle offline mode

[image]

Comment: At what scenario is offline or online mode.

Answer (score 15):

Gradle Offline Mode -> [image]

Gradle Online Mode -> [image]

Update : Even better in Android Studio Giraffe.

[image]

Comment: this icon is very confusing! thanks for this demonstration!