# Gradle doesn't sync in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, maven, gradle

I'm new to Android studio and I'm trying to set up a new project but I face this error message:

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.4/gradle-7.0.4.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.4/gradle-7.0.4.pom
Required by:
    project :
Add google Maven repository and sync project
Open File
```

I searched the Gradle website and found out 7.0.4 which was set on my Android studio by default, does not exist in the official repository.
So I downloaded another version (7.4.1) and changed the version in the `build.gradle` file but it didn't solve the problem. I downloaded Gradle by using the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and it still doesn't work. Then I tried to use the gradle plugin offline by turning on the offline mode and changing the location in `file > settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build tools > Gradle` and it shows me this error message:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 available for offline mode.

Possible solution:
 - Disable offline mode and rerun the build
```

It seems that com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 is nowhere...
I checked the version in `Project Structure...` and it's 7.4.1 exactly what it is supposed to be. My Android version is 2020.3.1.
I'm stuck. How can I fix this? My project doesn't sync and I can't even start...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#groovy Check this if this solves your problem

Answer (score 9):

For me worked changing the *Gradle JDK* to *Embedded JDK (JetBrains Runtime version 11.01.12)* in:

> **file** > **settings** > **Build, execution, deployment** > **build tools** > **gradle**

Answer (score 4):

## Option 1

You can try this

1. Install gradle manually on [gradle official website](https://gradle.org/releases/)
2. Extract gradle.zip file (remember the location)
3. Open **android studio > file > settings > Build, execution,
   deployment > build tools > gradle**
4. In **use gradle from** select **spesified location** and go to your gradle
   location (Example, C:/gradle/gradle7.0.4)

After this, gradle problem should fix, and try to disable gradle offline mode

## Option 2

1. In **file > project structure > Project**
2. Set gradle plugin to 7.1.2 and gradle version to 7.4.1

Comment: Failed. None of the options worked. still shows the first error message...

Comment: Can you edit your question, post your gradle project and gradle module code, current error code and gradle-wrapper.properties. Make sure you have internet connection when sync project. You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67705031/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio-4-2) too

Answer (score 0):

In the build.gradle Project level set classPath as follow:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"

    }
}
```

in the gradle-wrapper.properties set :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
```

Disable gradle offline mode , use VPN and sync your gradle

Comment: Not working. Still the first error appears.

Comment: Did you use VPN ?

Comment: Connect to VPN and try opening this link : https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.4/gradle-7.0.4.pom if you can download it make sure that the google() repository is the first one

Comment: I did... exactly what you said. Not working.

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart in android studio menu

Comment: I think your VPN not working for android studio try another one.

Comment: Still no result...

Comment: That may be it.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

Step one:

1.1.    Open file > project structure > Project
1.2.    Set gradle plugin to 7.1.2 and gradle version to 7.4.1

Step two

2.1.    Find and open In the build.gradle (Project:  ) level.
2.2.    Find the first repository inside buildscript and replace it with the following;

`repositories{ google() mavenCentral() }`

2.3.    Also find the second repository inside allprojects and replace it with the following;

`repositories{ google() mavenCentral() }`

2.4.    Then find classpath inside dependencies and replace it with the following:

`dependencies{ classpath “com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4” }`

Step Three

3.0.     Make sure you are connected to the internet, then click the Sync button.

Answer (score 0):

I had a Flutter Project with this problem - the solution was:

1. From your project root go to `/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`
2. Updated `distributionUrl` ->  `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip`

That was it.

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to install Android Gradle Plugin Version 7.3.1
2. you need to install Gradle Vesion 7.5.1
3. delete the .idea folder android /.idea it will automatically load later don't worry don't change file .
4. run command Reload All from dist
5. run Sync Project Gradle command
   these commands are at the top of File-e I have a Mac M1