# showing this Gradle error when trying to run flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I updated the Gradle from android studio. and when I try to run the project in vs code (Yes I already changed inside the build Gradle file too) showing this error.

```
 What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.1/gradle-7.4.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.1/gradle-7.4.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71508591/gradle-doesnt-sync-in-android-studio

Comment: @griffins no its not, the answer didn't even fixed for him (who asked question)   :(

Comment: well have you tried the suggestion download gradle manually and install it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#groovy Check this and tell us if this helps

Comment: It isaying that for 7.3+ the classpath plugin is 7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gradle plugin has different versions in project level `build.grade` and `gradle-wrapper.properties` Here is the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#groovy) about this