# I am facing an issue with android studio while generating a build

Tags: android, android-studio, build, build.gradle

Below attached the attachment, how to fix this issue
[image]

Comment: Try this thread- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67705031/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio-4-2

Comment: disable offline mode from `android studio -> gradle -> toggle offline mode` also check the version of your dependecies

Answer (score 0):

Edited after suggestion:

Try to connect your studio/gradle with internet. Then,

- Invalidate Cache/Restart
- Clean Project
- Sync gradle files
- Build project/Run

Comment: `Try to connect your phone/emulator with internet` how would this make a difference when compiling ? connecting android studio/gradle with the internet makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

enable online mode in android studio.

android studio -> gradle -> toggle offline mode -> enable to online mode

Comment: Tried 
But couldn't find any luck